# Cannot Boot into Ubuntu after updating Nvidia Proprietary Drivers to 455

Tags: grub2, nvidia, initramfs

I'm having some serious issues getting my PC to boot after updating packages, including my Nvidia drivers. They were updated through a "partial upgrade", which usually goes fine when I've had to update the drivers before, but now, when trying to boot, I get `initramfs unpacking failed: decoding failed` with no other output.

Now, using the Grub menu, I have tried entering the Ubuntu recovery menu so I can try some common fixes in the terminal, but it never takes me to the recovery menu. Instead, it gets stuck after a series of lines output, which don't seem to explain why it "hangs" or "freezes" (the cursor at the bottom no longer blinks and gets stuck on or off). I've tried running recovery mode with the debug parameter as well to try and get more detailed output, but I can't see any immediate issues with the lines printed.

The output of recovery mode (with the debug parameter) as it hangs is the following image: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/486937095923826710/780605563608105012/IMG_20201123_202656.jpg

My main goal is to just get into recovery mode, and then I can troubleshoot what's causing initramfs to fail.

EDIT: The dmesg log can be found here: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/315258983399161866/780644249464471572/dmesg

Comment: Do you have a Live CD/USB nearby? Boot with that and mount your partitions. This will give you the ability to read the logs and hopefully resolve the issue.

Comment: I'm using the LiveUSB to look through the boot.log file in /var/log/. Is this the right file I should be looking at? The time stamp is right, but it doesn't seem to have any errors, all OK.

Comment: I've found the output lines that show during boot in dmesg. Is it safe to link this log here for troubleshooting (i.e. does it contain sensitive information)?

Comment: The log shouldn't contain any sensitive information, as it's just a boot log. You can edit your post above to include the log data 

Comment: Looking through the log, I see this near the bottom: `Lockdown: Xorg: raw io port access is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7`. This generally means there's a problem with the Nvidia Optimus driver ... which you probably already know. Does your machine also have integrated graphics? If you go into the BIOS and disable "Hybrid Graphics" temporarily, that should get you into safe mode. From there you can attempt to repair the Nvidia driver issue.

Answer (score 1):

After trying the LiveUSB Ubuntu installation, it somehow made my regular installation boot with the same graphical errors that not booting with "safe mode" enabled had when running from LiveUSB. So, adding `nomodeset` to the regular boot script in GRUB let me boot into my PC!

And low and behold, starting up "software and updates" presented me with the partial upgrade again, revealing that all Nvidia 450 libraries were upgraded to 455 *except* for `libnvidia-fbc1-###`, which is probably why everything was messed up. No idea why the upgrade didn't perform correctly the first time or how to avoid it, but at least this wasn't as bad as some Windows issues.